# Assets thumbs not being generated

Tags: assets

All of a sudden, thumbs are not showing in Assets. The folders are being created in the cache/assets/thumbs folders when files are uploaded, but no image is generated.

The odd part is that in my dev environment the thumbs are being created.

2.8.1 EE
2.4 Assets

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on the affected folders? Perhaps there's a setting that's off? Has anything changed on your server and/or code recently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the server image generation modules were uninstalled during a routine patch upgrade. The servers are managed on Rackspace. It took hours on the phone with RS to figure it out.